# Firebase Phone Authentication, Missing Client Identifier

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am currently trying to implement phone authentication for my react-native expo application using the react-native-firebase library.

Normal Authentication with username and password works just fine. But I need to implement phone authentication for my app.

I have the following code:

```
import {
  Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import styles from "../../styles/base";

function RegisterScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Authenticated");
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    console.log(auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting);
    auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("*************").then(() => {
      console.log("successfull");
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log("error");
    });
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.container}
      behavior="padding"
    >
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={handleSignUp}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.accountText} onPress={() => navigation.replace("Login")}>I already have an account.</Text>
      </View>

    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

export default RegisterScreen;
```

I have hardcoded a phone number that i have access to, but when trying to sign in with this number i get the following error:

```
[Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.]
```

I know that i have to implement either safety net or reCAPTCHA. The Problem is the google guide is outdated (some links are deprecated) and doesn't provide any code examples. I would prefer reCAPTCHA since i need the app to work on both android and IOS.
I have searched everywhere but i can't find any example on how to implement it. For manual testing purposes i have even tried to:

```
auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
```

But this too doesn't solve the problem. I have tried to implement the reCAPTCHA on my own since i wasn't able to find any good examples, but I wasn't able to. I used the following dependency and guide: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/

I would really like to see a working example using the packages that i use.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix your issue ?